# Testing Code in C# Visual Studio 2013 (Method Name Does Not Exist In Current Context)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I am trying to test some methods but it is saying "The name [method] does not exist in the current context."

To test the methods `AddUnsynchronizedPing()`, `GetUnsynchronizedPings()`, and `SetAllPingsSynchronized()` I had to create a Ping object, which I did.

The methods are from my `DataManager` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using BB.Mobile.Models;
using SQLite;

namespace BB.Mobile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class to provide a single interface for interacting with all SQLite data operations for stored tracking points.
/// </summary>
/// 
class DataManager
{
    private SQLiteConnection db = null;

    public DataManager()
    {
        if (this.db == null)
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(
             System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
             "bb.db3");

            db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTable<Ping>(); 
            db.CreateTable<PingGroup>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will compile and return all matching unsynchronized ping data from the SQLite database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<PingGroup> GetUnsynchronizedPings()
    {
        List<PingGroup> unsynchronizedPings = new List<PingGroup>();

        // TODO: Retrieve all unsynchronized pings from the SQLite database and return them to the caller.
        //var pGroup = db.Get<PingGroup>();
        //var pGroupList = db.List<PingGroup>();

        var pGroups = db.Table<PingGroup>();
        foreach (var pGroup in pGroups)
        {
           var pings = db.Query<Ping>("select * from Pings where PingGroupID = " + pGroup.ID.ToString());
           pGroup.Pings = pings;
        }

        return unsynchronizedPings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert a single ping group into the SQLite ping database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pingGroup"></param>
    public void AddUnsynchronizedPing(PingGroup pingGroup)
    {
        // TODO: Add the passed ping group parameter into the SQLite database as new/unsynchronized.
        if (pingGroup != null)
        {
            // Add ping group to the database.
            db.Insert(pingGroup);

            foreach (var ping in pingGroup.Pings)
            {
                ping.PingGroupID = pingGroup.ID;
            }

            db.InsertAll(pingGroup.Pings);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mark all open and unsynchronized pings in the database as synchronized.
    /// </summary>
    public void SetAllPingsSynchronized()
    {
        db.DeleteAll<PingGroup>();
        db.DeleteAll<Ping>();
    }
}
}
```

Where I am testing said methods is in the `OnCreate` method of my in my `MainActivity` class. Here is said method:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        Ping p = new Ping()
        {
            Latitude = +0.000000,
            Longitude = -90.000000,
            DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
        };

        AddUnsynchronizedPing(p);
        GetUnsynchronizedPings(p);
        SetAllPingsSynchronized(p);
        GetUnsynchronizedPings(p);

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        this.userSettings = new Settings(this.ApplicationContext);
        //this.setLayoutToSettings();
        if (this.userSettings.isUserLoggedin()) // check for logged in user to switch between layouts
        {
            this.setLayoutToSettings();
            InitializeAlarms();
        }
        else
        {
            this.setLayoutToLogin();
        }
    }
```

As implied above, the methods `AddUnsynchronizedPing()`, `GetUnsynchronizedPings()`, and `SetAllPingsSynchronized()` in the `MainActivity`class are returning the "The name [method] does not exist in the current context" error.

Comment: You need to create an instance of DataManager since those methods are instance methods on the DataManager class.  Also, none of those methods accept a Ping instance as an argument.

Comment: @Jason Hmm. Could you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of DataManager first (you also need to be sure DataManager is public)

```
DataManager mgr = new DataManager();

// this method requires a PingGroup argument, so you need to instantiate and pass one
PingGroup pg = new PingGroup();
mgr.AddUnsynchronizedPing(pg);

var pings = mgr.GetUnsynchronizedPings();
mgr.SetAllPingsSynchronized();
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it will not run with DataManager as a public class. Hmmm.

Comment: It gives an error for the AddUnsynchronizedPing method:

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'BB.Mobile.Models.PingGroup' is less accessible than method 'BB.Mobile.DataManager.AddUnsynchronizedPing(BB.Mobile.Models.PingGroup)'

It also gives an error for the GetUnsychronizedPing method:

Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BB.Mobile.Models.PingGroup>' is less accessible than method 'BB.Mobile.DataManager.GetUnsynchronizedPings()'

Comment: Is your PingGroup class public?

Comment: Alright, that was issue. Made both Ping and PingGroup public as well. Now for the code above, that would go in the `MainActivity` class and not the `DataManager` class?

Answer (score 0):

Make the DataManager class public.

```
public class DataManager
```